# Transition Panels Sequentially Instead of all together (D3)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a bunch of square grids being constructed using two while loops. I am attempting to make them fade in individually, one at a time using the .transition function. However, I am noticing that all are transitioning in together at once. I realize D3 is asynchronous, but I am wondering if there is any way to override this.

See snippet below and link for fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxtjddvr/

Thanks!

```
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var xLoc = 0;
var yLoc = 100;


while (x < 3) {

    svg.append('rect')
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d,i) {
        return i*2000
    })
    .duration(5000)
    .attr('width', '100')
    .attr('height', '100')
    .attr('x', xLoc)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .style('stroke', 'white' )

    while (y < 3) {
        svg.append('rect')
        .transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .attr('id', 'trans')
        .attr('width', '100')
        .attr('height', '100')
        .attr('x', xLoc)
        .attr('y', yLoc)
        .style('stroke', 'white' )
        yLoc += 100;
        y++;
    }
    yLoc = 100;
    y=1;
    xLoc += 100
    x++;
}
```

Comment: D3 isn't asynchronous. Your delay isn't working as expected because you have an outer loop that adds the elements and aren't referencing that loop variable. I'd recommend refactoring and having data that determines all rectangles. That way the `.delay()` will work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need loops in d3 and you don't need window timers, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/nxtjddvr/3/) is a rough idea of how to use d3 to do what you want...

```
var data = [32, 57, 112];
    var height = 300;
    var width = 300;

    d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .style('background-color', 'lightgrey')

    var svg=d3.select('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)


        svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
        .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'trans')
        .attr('width', '100')
        .attr('height', '100')
        .attr('x', function(d, i){
           return (d-1)*100 
         })
        .attr('y', function(d,i){
           return Math.floor((i/3))*100
         })
         .attr("opacity",0)
        .style('stroke', 'white' )
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d,i) {
            return i*2000
        })

        .duration(5000)

        .attr("opacity",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sort of recursive setTimeout approach. The idea is this: fade out, wait, fade out, wait, etc. Until you're done.

Something like this:

```
var elementCount = 3;

function chainReaction() {
    // remove your element here

    elementCount--;

    if(elementCount > 0) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            chainReaction();
        }, 500);
    }
}

chainReaction();
```

Here's a quick JSFiddle that does it: http://jsfiddle.net/dgrundel/5poes17s/2/